# Why doesn't hyphenation seem to work with character :before and drop cap ::first-letter?

Tags: css, hyphenation

Here's a code snippet for the html portion:

```
<p class="chapter">Introduction</p>
```

With the following css, "Introduction" is **not** hyphenated with either zooming or window resizing?

I do not understand why **hyphens** work everywhere with:

```
body {
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;   /* manual (default), auto, none */
       -moz-hyphens: auto;
        -ms-hyphens: auto;
         -o-hyphens: auto;
           -hyphens: auto;
}
```

**except** in the following = with character :before and ::first-letter code for drop caps ...

```
.chapter:before {
    display: inline;

 /*
    content:     '\00a7\00a0';    // § + non-breaking space //
 */
    content:     '§';
    /* don't need the above non-breaking space with this padding */
    padding-right: 0.3em;

    font-size:   1.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:       #600;
}

/*
    https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/drop-caps/
*/
.chapter + p::first-letter {
    float:         left;

    font-family:   Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
    color:         #903;
    font-size:     250%;

    line-height:   100%;      /* original = 1 */

    position:      relative;  /* tweaking the placement ... */
    top:           -.05em;
    padding-right: 0.06em;    /* original = 5px */
    padding-left:  0.00em;    /* original = 0px */
}
```

Here's a snapshot or two ...

[image]

[image]

Please note that the 1st does not hyphenate, but the 2nd does???

To add to the mystery, if I use "Introduction q", that is, **> one word**, hyphenation works, but **not = one word**?

Thanks bunches and bunches ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
body {
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;   /* manual (default), auto, none */
       -moz-hyphens: auto;
        -ms-hyphens: auto;
         -o-hyphens: auto;
           -hyphens: auto;
}
```

... use this:

```
body {
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;   /* manual (default), auto, none */
       -moz-hyphens: auto;
        -ms-hyphens: auto;
         -o-hyphens: auto;
           -hyphens: auto;

    overflow-wrap: break-word;  /* BINGO! */
    word-wrap:     break-word;         
}
```

Just credits to:

Ref: https://justmarkup.com/articles/2015-07-31-dealing-with-long-words-in-css/